# i can't solve maven building error failure

Tags: java, maven

I get a error when I use maven to build my project.so please help!
thank you for your help

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly
>   (make-assembly) on project newstart-app-ithelp: Execution
>   make-assembly of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly failed:
>   For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. cause
>   : Execution make-assembly of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly failed:
>   For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. Stack
>   trace :  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly
>   (make-assembly) on project newstart-app-ithelp: Execution
>   make-assembly of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly failed:
>   For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>com.feinno.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>root-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>newstart.app</groupId>
<artifactId>newstart-app-ithelp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>newstart-app-ithelp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.newstart.app.ithelp.ITHelpBean</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.feinno.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>feinno-app-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-aop</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-beans</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-context</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-core</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-tx</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-expression</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>IKAnalyzer</groupId>
        <artifactId>IKAnalyzer</artifactId>
        <version>6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>linq4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>linq4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://10.10.208.92:8081/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: It says,  The groupId cannot be empty. post the `pom.xml`

Comment: What were you trying to do exactly? Which command? Also, did you read the error message?

Comment: Are you running mvn clean install, or?

Comment: Maybe you could try and clean the .m2-folder manually, and then run mvn install on your project? Then after that, run your above command to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 28):

I have fixed this issue by deleting local `.m2/repository` folder. The build is successful now.

Comment: I hate inscrutable errors like this...  This worked for me too.  If you're running windows and don't know where to find this, just go to `%username%\.m2` .

Comment: This worked for me. My mvn build had failed earlier with checksum error, because of issues with our internal nexus. After that failed build, I got "Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:assembly failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty." error.

Comment: I just had the same problem. Deleting the .m2 directory (~/.m2 on Mac) solved it.

Answer (score 7):

And mine has a different solution. I had a POM that had a `<dependencyManagement>` entry for the jar **without** any `<version>`, **and** it had a `<dependencies>` entry for the jar **with** a `<version>`. Plus, the parent POM had a `<dependencyManagement>` entry **with** the same `<version>`. Apparently this confused Maven (3.3). The build worked fine, but the packaging did not.

Fix: remove `<dependencyManagement>` entry in the child POM, and remove the `<version>` from the `<dependencies>` entry in the child POM.

In code, here is the broken situation:

```
Parent pom.xml:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

Child pom.xml:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Post fix: parent POM is the same, child pom has just this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your maven build output, there should be some warnings that say .pom is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available. Delete all the artifacts corresponding to those poms and rebuild, you need not delete the entire repository.

Comment: Not sure why Google brought me to this question (I was searching an error about missing classes in a plugin), but thanks, your answer got me on the right track! I didn't want to delete or rename my repository because I suspect it contains jars that do not exist elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

recently I stuck with the same problem. I turns that assembly-plugin doesn't propagate/report errors with dependencies:

```
[DEBUG] Resolving project dependencies transitively.
[DEBUG] com.g.....0.4-SNAPSHOT (selected for null)
[DEBUG]           org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]           org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]         trove:trove:jar:1.0.2:compile (selected for compile)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
....
[INFO] p.....mo ....................................... FAILURE [57.144s]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single (full) on project p...o: Execution full of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
```

that's all what I've got from assembly-plugin. eg. compiler warns about the broken stuff:

```
[WARNING] error reading /var/lib/jenkins/...org/hyperic/sigar/1.6.3.82/sigar-1.6.3.82.jar; error in opening zip file
[WARNING] error reading /var/lib/jenkins/.../org/hyperic/sigar/1.6.3.82/sigar-1.6.3.82.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Thus, if you've been stuck in this trouble, invoke `mvn dependency:tree` to troubleshoot the dependency.

Comment: Thank you for posting this; your solution was exactly my problem. Now I know enough that I think I can reproduce [MASSEMBLY-664](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-664), should I choose to expend the energy on doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this building a spring boot 2.2 project.
Turns out the problem was an out of date maven-assembly-plugin. Our build specified 2.3 but spring boot's bom requested at least 3.1.1. Bumping to 3.2.0 (the latest at time of writing) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Maven version.
I had the same problem and nothing worked until I downloaded and installed a later version of Maven (from 3.2 to 3.6). This solved the issue for me.
Also I was using Java 11 and from what I see here:
https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

```
Maven 3.3+ requires JDK 1.7+
Maven 3.2 requires JDK 1.6+
Maven 3.0/3.1 requires JDK 1.5+
```

Answer (score 0):

For me temporarily removing the following dependency from the plugin management section solved it for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

The previous error message:

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:display-plugin-updates failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId can not be empty. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that Maven was unable to download the artifactories on its own during the build phase. So I have to run,

```
mvn clean install
```

explicitly and it worked perfectly.