# Failed to execute goal Maven/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Ok, I'm new to Maven and Eclipse and I have to run an existing project. I'm trying to use the command `eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` but it shows me the following error:

> [INFO] Adding support for WTP version 2.0.
>   [INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null 
>   [INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 17.261 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-05T10:36:20-03:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/88M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal *org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse* (default-cli) on project core-framework: Execution default-cli of goal *org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse* failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]

I've tried all the possible solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183418/i-cant-solve-maven-building-error-failure) and it didn't worked. My POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.empresa1</groupId>
    <artifactId>e1-framework-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>e1-framework-utils</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>pentaho-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <version.log4j>2.8.2</version.log4j>
        <version.junit>4.12</version.junit>
        <version.commonslang>3.3.2</version.commonslang>
        <version.freemaker>2.3.23</version.freemaker>
        <version.resteasey-multipart>3.0.11.Final</version.resteasey-multipart>
        <version.commonscollections>3.2.2</version.commonscollections>
        <version.zip4j>1.3.2</version.zip4j>

        <version.core-framerwork>2.2.0</version.core-framerwork>
        <!--  <version.test-core-framerwork>2.2.0</version.test-core-framerwork>-->
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                    http://localhost:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <!--  <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>-->
                    <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <testSource>1.7</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.empresa1</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${version.core-framerwork}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${version.freemaker}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${version.resteasey-multipart}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${version.commonslang}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${version.commonscollections}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help is useful

Comment: read here [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.htm)

Comment: `eclipse:eclipse` is a _deprecated_ command that should no longer be used. If you use Maven and Eclipse, create a new Eclipse project through m2e. File -> New -> Project.. and choose Maven Project.

Comment: Follow the recommendation of @JFMeier cause the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is retired.

Comment: @JFMeier , thanks for the tip!

Comment: TO run your project do  mvn eclipse:eclipse at your project's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JFMeier said in the comments, the command *eclipse:eclipse* is now deprecated.

To update the project, right click the project, select ***Maven*** -> ***Update Project...*** -> Check the box ***Force Update of Snapshots/Release*** and click ***OK***.

That will do.