# 'Error: java: cannot access java.util.function.Function' - while trying to use WebDriverWait

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm using Maven and Intellij, project set for jdk-12.0.2, maven in pom 1.8 and when trying to run this code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement el =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("https://poczta.wp.pl")));
```

I get :

> Error:(37, 30) java: cannot access java.util.function.Function   class
>   file for java.util.function.Function not found

Pointing to 'wait'

Tried changing maven in pom from 1.7 to 1.8. > `Invalidate cache/Restart`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given you have [`maven` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/info) my expectation is that your project is being managed by Maven hence built by [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) so your IDE language level settings might derive from what is defined in the [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

I would recommend setting project language level in:

1. [Maven pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) like:

   ```
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   ```
2. [In Idea on Project Properties page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-page.html) you can choose the Language Level for each module

   [image]

More information:

- [Selenium Webdriver Tutorial with JAVA: How to set up a TestNG maven based project from scratch](https://experitest.com/blogs/testng_framework_maven/)
- [stop IntelliJ IDEA to switch java language level every time the pom is reloaded (or change the default project language level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037657/stop-intellij-idea-to-switch-java-language-level-every-time-the-pom-is-reloaded/27037879)

Comment: This can also be related to corrupted dependencies, in that case, it can be fixed by removing your .m2/corrupted-file-path
Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555124

Answer (score 3):

I was having same problem, created project using JDK 11 but project setting was still using Language 7 (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S)

Using selenium version 3.141.59

**Below were my original settings**

[image]
[image]

**Got it fixed by**

1. Adding below to **pom.xml** inside build section but after pluginManagement

   ```
   <plugins><plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <source>8</source>
     <target>8</target>
   </configuration>
   ```

[image: changes in pom.xml]

2. Change module setting by (File -> Project Structure or using keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) And change language level to 8 - Lambda, type annotation etc. as shown in below image

[image]